# Remove c++ langage and unnecessary package from visual studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++

i want to remove c++ language development from visual studio 2012 express for desktop to be faster, i just use c# and Wpf, plus my pc is not so fast.

so using the Total Remover app let me chose the packages to remove
bat i don't know what to uninstall exactly may i get some help on this ?

**i just use c# and wpf**. what is the unnecessary package to remove from the list.
without breaking visual studio.

[image: list of installed vs packages]
[image]

And thank you

Comment: Not really an answer but, I recall seeing that Visual Studio 2015 had better support for this at install time, and the Community version basically replaces the "Express" versions and has nearly the complete feature set. Also if your after performance improvements I do not think you will get much, just a little less disk usage.

Comment: thanks for the reply i did try Visual Studio 2015 but it was very very slow on my pc thats why i use vs 2012 and it's more than 1Gb to save if removing c++

Comment: 2005-2013 did have separate cut-down express versions that did not have everything integrated, depending on what you are developing. e.g. "Visual C# Express" and "Visual Web Developer Express". The Wikipedia page appears to detail them all, MS seems to have removed/buried the old express edition pages. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#2005.E2.80.932010_products

Comment: This is all configurable from the installer.

Comment: no cody on vs 2010 it was

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if the modules are not loaded, it won't impact your performance. Unless you had very serious storage issues, you should not worry, it probably won't make it run faster.

Have you tried running the installer again? It may offer you some options.